# CPU usage does not match Task Manager, PerformanceCounter or ManagementObjectSearcher

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, performancecounter

I am just trying to get accurate CPU usage that matches Task Manager.  So far I have tried four recommended methods that do not work.

First, I have tried the similar solutions or suggestions given that I could find.  The code sample here uses four methods, all of which are inaccurate.  Second, I know that Task Manager fluctuates and depends on when it is sampled.  That still does not account for the differences.  Lastly, I know there are different methods, and that Task Manager uses just one method.  Since this is intended for general users, it needs to be close to Task Manager.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //*** Method 1 & 2
    PerformanceCounter cpuCounterPi = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
    PerformanceCounter cpuCounterP = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

    //*** method 3
    ManagementObjectSearcher query1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select loadpercentage from win32_processor");

    //*** Mixed method usage below
    CounterSample csPi1, csPi2, csP1, csP2;
    double cpuPercentagePi, cpuPercentageP, cpuPercentageLoad;
    int count = -1;
    Boolean alternate = false;

    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        //***Method 1 & 2
        if (alternate)
        {
            csPi1 = cpuCounterPi.NextSample();
            cpuPercentagePi = CounterSample.Calculate(csPi2, csPi1);
            csP1 = cpuCounterP.NextSample();
            cpuPercentageP = CounterSample.Calculate(csP2, csP1);

        }
        else
        {
            csPi2 = cpuCounterPi.NextSample();
            cpuPercentagePi = CounterSample.Calculate(csPi1, csPi2);
            csP2 = cpuCounterP.NextSample();
            cpuPercentageP = CounterSample.Calculate(csP1, csP2);
        }
        alternate = !alternate;

        if (count==5) { textBox.Clear(); count = 0; }
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "\nProcessor Information (Method 1)         " + cpuPercentagePi.ToString();
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "\nProcessor  (Method 2)                          " + cpuPercentageP.ToString();
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "\nProcessor ½  (Method 2 divided by 2)   " + (cpuPercentageP/2).ToString();
        //*****  Method 3 ****
        ManagementObjectCollection cpuColl = query1.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in cpuColl)
        {
            cpuPercentageLoad = Convert.ToDouble(mo["loadpercentage"]);
        }
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text +  "\nProcessor Load  (Method 3)                " + cpuPercentageLoad.ToString() + "\n";

    }
```

Here are two samples comparing to task manager.
[image]
[image]

From the picture you can see I have a dual core CPU, with four logical processors.  The CPU is a Intel Skylake i7-6650U, running Windows 10.

Thanks

For reference - These links are similar:
[PerformanceCounter reporting higher CPU usage than what's observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391455/performancecounter-reporting-higher-cpu-usage-than-whats-observed)
[How to get the CPU Usage in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c?rq=1)
[Calculate CPU usage for a Windows process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364801/calculate-cpu-usage-for-a-windows-process)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 cores but 4 threads, so you need to divide by 4, not 2. Also your WMI method I suspect will only be checking 1 core. Check if there are in fact multiple `win32_processor` objects available.

Comment: If you notice, one method does divide by two.  If I divide by four, then the only time it matches at 100%, it will say 25% and will be horribly off. So no matter how I look at it, performanceCounter is way off.  I will look into the multiple win32_processor objects.

Comment: I think performanceCounter can be set to read each core, but as I understand things win32_processor reads the entire processor.  I see no way to read individual cores with loadpercentage, thus it seems it should read entire CPU load..  I am certainly not an expert at all though.