# Why Does Windows Have Duplicate Performance Counters

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, performancecounter

I was looking into a bug where PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex was giving me a buffer size of 0 and discovered that there are 2 counters for "% Processor Time" and we were using the last one in the list (index 6 and 4676). The spanish language pack only has this counter once (index 6). I was curious as to why there would be 2 counters for the same thing in English and if there was a valid reason, why is it not included in the Spanish language pack.

Using Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Different categories, "Processor" vs "Processor Information".  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23392347/17034

Comment: They aren't though. As I stated there are 2 indices for "% Processor Time". I am not using "Processor" or "Processor Information"